# How can I describe the use of "you" when referring to a group of people rather than the second party?

Tags: expressions

I have used the pronoun "you" instead of the more appropriate word "one" in the position of the pronoun when referring to a generic group. Then when realizing the slip, I've qualified the statement with "When I said 'you', I meant you in the pejorative, not you specifically".

What is the correct word or phrase to use instead of "pejorative" in the above? I discovered that "pejorative" has a more negative connotation than I intend.

Comment: Uhm, what? I don't understand what's being asked here at all. Please, expand or reword your question.

Comment: Are you looking for "plural"?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of generic 'you'?

Comment: Are you one of *them*?

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** based on the comment below: You should say "When I said 'you', I meant you in the general sense, not you specifically."  Makes sense, since "general" is the opposite of "specific"!  You could also use "generic" instead of "general" since you're using the generic "you" described below.

---

"You" is used *as a collective pronoun* when directed at a group of people.  From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun):

> a **collective noun** is a word used to define a group of objects, where objects can be people, animals, emotions, inanimate things, concepts, or other things. For example, in the phrase "a pride of lions," *pride* is a collective noun.

Barrie in the comments mentions "generic 'you'", which is an explicit or implicit use of "you" often used to refer to whomever might be around (or more often, reading) rather than being specifically directed at a group.  (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you.)

Comment: My regrets for the rough form of my question. In the past when speaking to an individual, I have used the pronoun 'you' instead of the more appropriate word 'one' in the position of the pronoun when referring to a generic group. Then when realizing the slip, qualifying the statement with the phrase "when I said 'you' I meant you in the pejorative not you specifically". My question is to find out if there is another word more appropriate than 'pejorative' in that context. I've heard others make similar statements using that phrase even though the word 'pejorative' itself has a negative context.

Comment: @Doug Updated. I've always used and seen used "I meant 'you' in the general sense".

Comment: Thank you. A very simple explanation. I appreciate your response. Now if I can just retrain myself to use that phrase....